# useReducer not updating the state inside context provider in NextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

useReducer inside context provider is only returning the initial state instead of updated state after dispatching and running reducer function.

When I console log the action inside reducer function, developer console logs the action object that I passed but it is not updated in the return of if statement.

GlobalContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const GlobalContext = createContext({
  auth: {
    user: Object,
    token: String,
    addUserData: Function,
  },
});

export default GlobalContext;
```

GlobalProvider.js

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import GlobalContext from './GlobalContext';

const initState = {
  auth: {
    user: {},
    token: null,
  },
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_USER_DATA') {
    console.log(action);

    return {
       ...state,
       auth: {
          user: JSON.parse(action.payload.user),
          token: action.payload.token,
       },
    };
  }
};

const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);

  const value = {
    auth: {
      user: state.auth.user,
      token: state.auth.token,
      addUserData: (user, token) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_USER_DATA', payload: { user, token } });
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default GlobalProvider;
```

Comment: Is this the actual code or have you simplified it for this example? Because right now your `reducer` doesn't do anything with `action.payload`, it just sets `auth.user` and `auth.token` to static strings, so it won't ever change. This has nothing to do with Next, and really almost nothing to do with React either.

Comment: Hello @Sheraff. Yes, I did. I just updated that with the exact same codes recently. Could you please let me know what would be the issue? FYI, currently, it only returns the initialState instead of the strings or the actual values. When I console log the action before returning the dispatch condition, it shows all the data. But it's not updated on the state. State just stays as it is in initialState.

Comment: Are you having the issue client side or server side? Is this component in a client-only branch? 

With Next13, you can't use stateful hooks on server components (inside the `app` folder, without a parent `"use client"`, it's a server component).

Also, with Next (even before 13), state setters don't update state server-side, only client side.

Comment: I am now working under /pages directory. I wrapped `<Component {...pageProps} />`  with the GlobalProvider in _app.jsx. I implemented to update the state on user login (on login.jsx page) just under axios request. Could that be an issue?

Comment: That all sounds to me like you're doing it right. If you log the `state` just below `useReducer` it doesn't change after dispatching?

Comment: No, it doesn't change after dispatching. State doesn't get updated.